# Asterisk + Android, communication service

Tags: android, sip, asterisk, pbx

I would like to make a simple project. Having two Android phones, I would like to send messages and call between them using an Asterisk PBX. I guess that I should program a SIP application for Android device to register on the PBX and be able to make calls and send messages.

Anyone any idea where to start? I'd very pleased to get new ideas or advice :)

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open source SIP softphones like sipdroid or csipsimple exist. You should be able to build on them, customize them, or just use them "as is" :-)

Answer (score 2):

I've used and can confirm that SIPDroid works with Asterisk:

https://market.android.com/details?id=org.sipdroid.sipua&feature=search_result

Other SIP apps that may be of use are:

- https://market.android.com/details?id=com.csipsimple&feature=search_result
- https://market.android.com/details?id=com.tcx.sip.ui&feature=search_result

An IAX app is also available though its not as reliable:

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bw.iax.ui&feature=search_result